# how to install a tar file with a command?

Tags: software-installation, tar

im search on many website to install it.but they sad if there is a INSTALL file,but in my file there no such of that named file.so,is there a way to install it from terminal?

Comment: Can you provide the `.tar` file content ? Each program should have unique ways to install it, the answer is depend to the content of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must extract the tar file, you can use something like this,

```
tar -xvzf filename
```

go into the extracted directory using `cd`.

There is several ways to install the program, depends on the program files.
But the most common one is using these commands below,

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Or using the `easy_install` from python.